# Enable Comments Box On Custom Post Type

Tags: posts, comments, customization

The wordpress theme I'm using doesn't support comments on one of its custom post types (Shows) and I've been trying to enable them. I added the code below to single-shows.php (copied from shows.php) and it shows previous comments that were already there but doesn't show the comments box to post new comments. I also modified the "supports" for the custom post type to include comments. I checked discussion settings and checked screen options - there's comments but no discussion checkbox.

```
<?php if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ){  ?>
                        <hr class="qt-spacer-m">
                        <?php  comments_template(); ?>
                    <?php } ?>
```

The site is [this](http://2017.boldbravemedia.com/).

[Here's an example show](http://2017.boldbravemedia.com/shows/courage-2-overcome/) with old comments appearing:

[Here's a post](http://2017.boldbravemedia.com/nycs-homeless-can-count-on-one-thing/) that has the correct comment box and all:

Hope someone can help! This is key to launching the site...

Comment: adding `comments` in `supports` should be enough to display that. maybe your theme do a filter of this part. try with a basic theme to look if you have the same result.

Comment: I don't want to lose all the customizations I did if I change the theme. I know it has something to do with the theme though because it would otherwise be supported...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is having a similar issue, the problem was that the child theme was not registering the custom post type. I had to change the "supports" there for it to work. Not ideal but it's fixed.